# sudo nautilus results in "cannot open display" error

Tags: command-line, unity, lightdm, display-manager, mir

```
$ gksudo nautilus
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(nautilus:6072): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

#### Troubleshooting attempts:

- Same error when using `gksu` and `sudo`.
- Also tried `export DISPLAY=:0.0`.
- Finally even tried installing `lightdm-gtk-greeter` and appending `[SeatDefaults]` in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` with `greeter-session=lightdm-gtk-greeter`

BTW: I'm running Ubuntu 15.04 x64 on a System76 laptop.

Answer (score 3):

From [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Running_X_apps_as_root):

> By default, and for security reasons, root will be unable to connect
>   to a non-root user's X server. There are multiple ways of allowing
>   root to do so, if it is necessary.

Before running `gksudo nautilus` you should allow root access.
To do this run:

```
xhost +SI:localuser:root
```

These also works: `xhost local:root` or just `xhost +`.

You can disallow with `xhost -SI:localuser:root` and `xhost -`.

See more [here](https://possiblelossofprecision.net/?p=896).

Answer (score 0):

look for nautilus-admin package (search in synaptic-packet-manager )...and try to install it maybe will fix your problem

credits to :

https://bitbucket.org/brunonova/nautilus-admin

Comment: `nautilus` is just an example. Same error occurs when launching any GUI program from Terminal using `sudo`/`su`/`gksudo`/`gksu`.